# Enable submit button after validation using parsleyjs

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

Does Parsley have an easy way to load a form with the submit button disabled and enable it what all validation requirements of the form have been met?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "easy" but what your after can be accomplished.

You need to [listen to the events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events) `parsley:form:success` and `parsley:form:error` to enable / disable the button.

You will also need to monitor the changes to each form field in order to force Parsley to validate. Tipically Parsley executes the validation once you click on `submit`. Since the submit is disabled, you'll need to trigger the validation manually.

So, here's a working example ([**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/9b2t0ub6/)):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="field" data-parsley-required />
    <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind Parsley to the form
    $("form").parsley();

    // Whenever parsley validates successfully, we enable the submit button
    $.listen('parsley:form:success', function(ParsleyForm) {
        ParsleyForm.$element.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    });

    // When a validation error occurs, we disable the submit button
    $.listen('parsley:form:error', function(ParsleyForm) {
        ParsleyForm.$element.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
    });

    // We need to monitor all form fields and force Parsley's validation manually
    // This will result in enabling or disabling the submit button
    $("form :input").change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').parsley().validate();
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that you'll need to make you monitor the changes of all fields (inputs, selects, textareas, etc).

Comment: Good starting point. I believe you can also use the `trigger` option (set it to `input`, say) and you won't need to call `validate` yourself.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Nice catch. I believe you're talking about `data-parsley-trigger`? If so, I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. [Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/5oLzfarn/1/). The validation of the field is indeed triggered, but the events `parsley:form:success` and `parsley::form:error` are never triggered (in the JSfiddle, you never get the `alert('success')`.

Comment: Ah, possible. The "before first submit" thing should probably be cleaned up.

Comment: I tried this and it works but I it has a side effect of all the validations firing for all my input showing up the error messages when it tab out of the first input on the form. I I have the following on all my inputs  data-parsley-trigger="focusout"

Comment: @MarkJohnston I see your issue. It will be tough to solve that with a simple solution. I guess you need to make sure that you need to disable the submit button. If you do, you have to find a way to prevent that, like adding an attibute to all fields that is changes the first time the user enters something in the input. It won't be a pretty solution though...

Comment: The `$.listen` should be replaced with `window.Parsley.on`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596353/console-msg-parsleys-pubsub-module-is-deprecated-use-the-corresponding-jquer

Answer (score 0):

The code below can be used, which loads a form with the submit button        disabled and enable it when certain validation requirements of the form have         been met:

```
function formValidation(oEvent) {
    oEvent = oEvent || window.event;
    var txtField = oEvent.target || oEvent.srcElement;
    var t1ck = true; //Enter Text Field ID/Name in place of 't1'
    var msg = " ";

    if(document.getElementById("t1").value.length < 3 ) { 
        t1ck = false; 
        msg = msg + "Text Entered should be minimun 3 char length";
    }
    //Enter Text Field ID/Name in place of 't1'

    if(document.getElementById("s1").value.length < 1 ) { 
        t1ck = false;
        msg = msg + " Select one of the options";
    }
    //Enter Select Field ID/Name in place of 's1'

    if(t1ck) {
        document.getElementById("btnSignUp").disabled = false; 
    }  
    //Enter submit button ID/Name in place of 'btnSignUp'
    else{
        document.getElementById("btnSignUp").disabled = true; 
    }
}
function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("btnSignUp").disabled = true;
    var frmMain = document.forms[0];
    frmMain.reset();
}
window.onload = function () {
    var btnSignUp = document.getElementById("btnSignUp");
    var btnReset = document.getElementById("btnReset"); //Enter reset button ID/Name in place of 'btnReset'

    var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
    var s1 = document.getElementById("s1");
    var t1ck = false;

    document.getElementById("btnSignUp").disabled = true;
    t1.onkeyup = formValidation;
    s1.onclick = formValidation;
    btnReset.onclick = resetForm;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not using [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) which is a jQuery plugin with out-of-the-box validations. In your case you are defining all the validations in pure javascript, which is not what the OP is after.