# Console-msg: "Parsley's pubsub module is deprecated; use the corresponding jQuery event method instead"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, parsley.js

Trying to display error-msgs in a Bootstrap-Popup, I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008008/display-parsley-errors-in-bootstrap-tooltip) from TheDude and have adjusted the event-names for ps2.1:

```
$.listen('field:error', function (fieldInstance) {

    arrErrorMsg = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
    errorMsg = arrErrorMsg.join(';');

    fieldInstance.$element
        .popover('destroy')
        .popover({
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'right',
            content: errorMsg
        })
        .popover('show');

});

$.listen('field:success', function (fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.popover('destroy');
});
```

This works wonderfully, but I'm getting a msg in the JS-Console: "**Parsley's pubsub module is deprecated; use the corresponding jQuery event method instead**". There are very few hits for that msg in Google, and I'm afraid I'm not (yet) sufficiently versed with Parsley to understand and fix this problem - would appreciate some help to make my code future-proof :-)

Comment: Sorry about the deprecation message. It's incorrect and I just fixed it.

Comment: Oh, that's even better - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I just was too impatient and started looking and it was easier than expected:
the `$.listen` needs to be changed into `window.Parsley.on`. That's it! :-)